# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myProject'

Tags: python, django, wsgi

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myProject' error, but I do not know the cause. I am glad if you tell me.

・ CentOS 7.2
・ Python 3.6
・ Django 2.0
・ apache 2.4

I set the virtual environment as follows

```
pip install virtualenv
mkdir xxx
cd xxx 
python3 -m venv xxx
source xxx/bin/activate
pip install mod_wsgi
mod_wsgi-express module-config
LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/username/myProject/myProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/home/username/myProject/myProject"
```

■ /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
LoadModule wsgi_module /home/username/myProject/myProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
WSGIPythonHome /home/username/myProject/myProject
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName xxx.com
  DocumentRoot /home/username

  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIDaemonProcess xxx python-home=/home/username/myProject/myProject python-path=/home/username/myProject/myProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup xxx
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/myProject/myProject/wsgi.py

  <Directory /home/username/myProject/myProject/static>
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/username/myProject/myProject>
      <Files wsgi.py>
          Require all granted
      </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

■ wsgi.py

```
import os,sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxx.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

The `WSGIPythonHome` directive or `python-home` option should point at the root directory for the Python virtual environment. This should be the same value as `sys.prefix` has when Python is run for that virtual environment.

The `WSGIPythonPath` directive or `python-path` option would then be set to your project code directory in which modules/packages exist, likely `/home/username/myProject` in your case.

Do not use these later options to point at the `site-packages` directory, use the first options for specifying the location of the virtual environment.

I would suggest since you are using daemon mode to add:

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
```

after the `LoadModule` line. Then remove the `WSGIPythonHome` and `WSGIPythonPath` and rely on `python-home` and `python-path` options on `WSGIDaemonProcess` instead.

BTW, `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` wouldn't be `xxx.settings`. You likely mean `myProject.settings`.

Also, it appears that you have your virtual environment being your project code directory. If that is the case, is not really recommended. Create the virtual environment as a distinct sub directory somewhere of its own. Don't intermingle it with your code as then it becomes really hard to remove the virtual environment and re-create it.