# there is a web app in django shows the ModelnotFound error

Tags: python, django

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'
```

to solve the above query
in the Django web app there is an error shows init.py there is word like `import _frozen_importlib_`

Comment: Add some code samples. What is your config? What is your code calling it? Did you install the library? Does it show up in `pip list`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myProject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511748/django-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-myproject)

Answer (score 0):

Install the 'crispy_forms' module using pip by running the following command in your terminal or command prompt:

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

This error message suggests that the module 'crispy_forms' is not installed.